# Как вывести порядковый номер каждой отдельной буквы в строке?

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно будет вывести порядковый номер буквы алфавита, допустим а - это 1, б - 2, и так далее. Может есть какой то свойство выведения позиции буквы в алфавите или надо делать 2 массива и сравнивать их?
Все что сделал это сделал строку и попытался разбить ее на буквы:
Вот мой код:

```
try
        {
            string message = text.Text;
            char[] letter = message.ToCharArray();
            foreach(char c in letter)
            {
                number_text.Text = c.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, $"Возникла ошибка - {ex}", "Уведомление");
        }
```

Заранее спасибо если укажите путь как можно это решить!!!

Comment: `number_text.Text += (int)(c - 'a' + 1);`

Comment: в дополнении к ответу тима, скажу что не стоит оборачивать всё в try-catch. В вашем коде лишь стоит добавить проверку на  то, что `text.Text` не равен `null`. Других исключений в вашем фрагменте кода быть не может

Comment: и чтобы работать со строкой как с массивом символом, нет необходимости вызывать `ToCharArray`

Comment: @iikuzmychov у меня все вышло за одним исключением надо учитывать регистр букв, я как бы сделал это, но отдельно, не знаю как вместе их проверять и отдельно выполнять вычисления позиций?

Comment: @iikuzmychov вот мой код: string message = text.Text;
            if(message != String.Empty)
            {
                foreach(char c in message)
                {
                    if(Char.IsUpper(c))
                    {
                        number_text.Text += (int)(c - 'А' + 1);
                    }
                    else if (Char.IsLower(c))
                    {
                        number_text.Text += (int)(c - 'а' + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Comment: вы можете перед приведением типов приводить символ в нижний регистр используя `символ.ToLower()`. Тогда выйдет так: `number_text.Text += (int)(c.ToLower() - 'a' + 1); `